# ios programming - overriding static library inside a static library at application level

Tags: ios, linker, static-libraries

I am very new to the field of ios programming and working with linker is just a whole new world to me. I would try my best to be precise about my question.

Context: Static library linking in an ios project using xcode.

Problem:

**Problem members**:
3 static libraries.

libTestLibA.a

libTestLibB.a

libTestLibB_mine.a -- same functionality as libTestLibB.a -- same classes/methods everything.

**Problem description**

I am making an app using libTestLibA.a.

libTestLibA has some classes that depend on some classes from libTestLibB. Hence libTestLibA.a has libTestLibB.a compiled in itself.

Now, I have my own library named libTestLibB_mine. It has the exact same functionality as that of libTestLibB. Same methods / classes for same functionality. I want libTestLibA to use libTestLibB_mine instead of libTestLibB. I just have compiled static libraries (.a) for each of the problem members , ie, libTestLibA, libTestLibB and libTestLibB_mine.

**Question**:

When I compile my application, can I force a static compiled library (libTestLibA.a) to make use of another library (libTestLibB_mine.a) instead of what it already contains (libTestLibB.a)? If yes, how? If not, is there some work around?

Much thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If A has already been statically complied against B, then I don't think you can replace B with B_mine. But as a workaround, I think what you might be looking for here is "Method Swizzling". What it does is, at runtime, replace the method of a class with another method (intercept the message and direct it somewhere else).

The following links should be useful to you.

- [CocoaDev Method Swizzling](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/MethodSwizzling)
- [JRSwizzle - open source library to make swizzling easier](https://github.com/rentzsch/jrswizzle)
- Be sure to read about the [dangers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5339276/what-are-the-dangers-of-method-swizzling-in-objective-c) of method swizzling too.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Swizzling would be tough because I am not sure what all classes / methods of B is A using internally because i dont have A's source code. B_mine is in reality just a different version of B that I want my app to use by forcing A to use B_mine .

I know that libTestLibA has libTestLibB's public headers and libTestLibB.a linked in it. This means B is statically compiled in A right?