# Is there an idiomatic Objective-C technique to make an init method return a stub implementation for testing?

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, factory-pattern, idioms, ocmockito

I am writing a unit test for a class `Foo`, which has a collaborator, `Bar`. I want to use a manually-built stub implementation of `Bar` in `Foo`'s test.

If I were doing this in Java, I would give `Foo` a `BarFactory` collaborator and inject a `MockBarFactory` in `Foo`'s test that always returned my `StubBar`.

I know this technique will work fine in Objective-C but it doesn't strike me as a particularly idiomatic thing to do in a dynamic language. I am wondering if I can do anything tricky that will cause `[[Bar alloc] init]` to return `StubBar` while I'm running my unit test but give me the normal implementation of `Bar` in "real life".

Or is the obvious factory pattern the most appropriate thing to use in this case?

Comment: I would not mixup code for unit-testing with "real life" code, how can you be sure your tests are fine if they behave differently?

Comment: @JonathanCichon I think that's a common thing to do when unit testing, isn't it? When you want to test some specific object or function (like `Foo` in this case) you can't always setup a complete testing environment for different reasons. Maybe `Foo` has to have a `Bar` property that's not actually relevant to the tests.

Comment: As I comment below, I would like to avoid adding stuff that compiles into my main target if it's solely used for unit testing.

Comment: @DrummerB In this case I need `Bar` to behave predictably so I can test all the code paths through `Foo` that are dependent on how `Bar` behaves.

Answer (score 1):

You can return a different object in `init`. That's why you're supposed to assign the return value of `[super init]` to `self`. Try something like this:

```
@implementation Bar 

- (id)init {
    if (UNIT_TEST) {
        self = [[StubBar alloc] init];
        if (self) {
            // do unit test init here
        }
    } else {
        self = [super init];
        if (self) {
            // do regular init here
        }
    }
    return self;
}

...

@end
```

Note: This should work under ARC. If you're not using ARC, make sure you release `self`, before assigning the new `StubBar` instance.

---

If you want to avoid compiling unit test related code into your main target:

```
@implementation Bar 

- (id)init {
#if UNIT_TEST
    self = [[StubBar alloc] init];
    if (self) {
        // do unit test init here
    }
#else
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // do regular init here
    }
#endif
    return self;
}

...

@end
```

---

If you want to completely separate unit testing and real code, you could just have two different versions of your `Bar` class. One will be compiled with the real code, the other one with the unit test target.

---

You can easily allocate an instance, without knowing the exact class type at compile time like this:

```
id someBar = [[someClass alloc] init]; // assuming someClass is of type Class
```

or:

```
id someBar = [[NSClassFromString(@"Bar") alloc] init];
```

The first one is preferable though. You could use this to have a default class type that you can change when you're unit testing. Either as a property of `Foo` itself, or a preprocessor macro that you redefine when unit testing.

Comment: While I can see how this would work, I don't like the idea of mixing unit testing stuff into my real codebase.

Comment: @RobertAtkins Added a couple more suggestions. There is really a ton of ways to do this, I don't think there is THE way, and as you mentioned factories would work just as well.

Comment: I don't understand how I'd implement your last suggestion in my case where `Bar` is constructed by the class-under-test _inside_ its implementation. The problem a Factory solves for you in Java is that `new` is a static call and can't be mocked out at runtime. The gist of my question is, "is there something clever I can do in Objective-C to get around the fact that `[Bar alloc]` is a static call?"

Comment: Also, the way we have our unit tests set up, the unit test target depends on the main target so defining the class twice won't work I don't think.

Comment: How would you assign the factory to `Foo` in Java? Is it a static variable? An ivar?

Comment: I don't think alloc is the static call you think it is. Remember, classes are objects too, so you can also do [Foo performSelector:@selector(alloc)]. I don't recommend this, but it's possible.

Comment: @DrummerB In Java you'd be using some kind of IoC container (like Spring) and have the implementation of `BarFactory` injected at runtime for live code, but you'd manually pass the `StubBar`-returning version in (either constructor injection or setter injection) in the unit test setup.

Comment: @casademora That's the kind of trick I was wondering if a) existed and b) was regularly used to accomplish my original goal.

Comment: You can replace the implementation of a method at runtime, if that's what you're looking for. It's called [Method Swizzling](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/MethodSwizzling). However I don't think this is a technique that is often used (for unit testing). You have to be very [careful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5339276/what-are-the-dangers-of-method-swizzling-in-objective-c).

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is something along the lines of [OCMock](http://ocmock.org).
It allows you to build mock objects from classes, protocols and it especially made for unit testing.