# What do messages give you in Objective C vs simple Method calls in C# and Java?

Tags: objective-c, language-design, message

I'm a C#/Java developer learning Objective C. At first I assumed "messages" were just a different name for method calls, so:

```
[person jumpInTheAir];
```

would just be the Objective C syntax for writing

```
person.jumpInTheAir();
```

But now I've read [here](http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/sthompson/understanding-objective-c-messaging) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C#Messages) and various other places that the concepts are actually not the same and can have different behaviours/advantages. However I'm still uncertain why the language designers would choose a *messaging* system over a more direct *method calling* system as in C# and Java.

**What advantages do messages bring to the Objective C programming language?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> At first I assumed "messages" were just a different name for method calls,

Yes and no. "Messages" are the Smalltalk and Objective-C terminology for method calls. The thing is, it's not only the terminology that differs, but the actual implementation too. There are 8 different possible combinations for matching the terminology, the syntax and the implementation, like this:

```
+-------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
|    terminology    |        syntax        |   implementation   |
+-------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
|  "method call"    | Simula (o.method())  |  static binding    | non-virtual C++ methods
+-------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
|  "method call"    | Simula               |  dynamic binding   |
+-------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
|  "method call"    | Smalltalk ([o meth]) |  static binding    |
+-------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
|  "method call"    | Smalltalk            |  dynamic binding   |
+-------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
| "message passing" | Simula               |  static binding    |
+-------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
| "message passing" | Simula               |  dynamic binding   |
+-------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
| "message passing" | Smalltalk            |  static binding    |
+-------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
| "message passing" | Smalltalk            |  dynamic binding   | Objective-C
+-------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
```

The combination the language designer choses is just a matter of taste.

> I'm still uncertain why the language designers would choose a messaging system over a more direct method calling system

Because it has some advantages, such as runtime interposition and introspection -- one can query and modify the behavior of classes, methods and objects at runtime. In the implementation of Objective-C, this have been done in a way such that it is very cheap, it has almost no overhead.

Answer (score 0):

[H2CO3 pointed out in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18945055/165108) that there are three things I might be referring to when I say "messages": **Terminology**, **Syntax** and **Implementation**.

Terminology and Syntax are down to personal taste, but implementation (static/dynamic binding) has some real consequences.

Pros:

- Dynamic binding can be used to add new methods to an existing class without subclassing. This seems to be a possible replacement for those used to [C# Extension Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx).
- It lets you inspect the methods available and change their implementation at runtime. See [Reflection](http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/stevez/archive/2012/11/27/c-to-objective-c-part-6-reflection.aspx) and [Method Swizzling in Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8636521/165108).

Cons:

- It can be argued that the extra layer adds complexity to both the syntax and usage.
- Dynamic binding adds some overhead over static typing, but this is rarely the bottleneck and it seems there are ways of getting around the overhead if it is really critical.