# How to set custom font family as system font in ios application

Tags: ios, fonts, uiapplication

I am working on an ios application in which i have to use custom fonts for UIs.
I know how to integrate new custom fonts in application. For that i have

1. Download font family files with .ttf extention.
2. Add them to resource bundle.
3. In info.plist file add with key Fonts provided by application.

This custom fonts shows effect. But what i want to do is, I want to set them as a systemFont. So i do not have to set them in all UI elements.

I want something like

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] systemFont:@"Arial"];
```

Is this possible? Can any one help me with this?

Comment: There was

 ` [[UILabel appearance] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"YourFontName" size:17.0]];`

which os now deprecated. Take a look at the link of StuartM - thtas a good answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had your same problem when updating my iOS app for iOS 7. I wanted to set a custom font for the entire application, even for controls you are not allowed to customize their font (e.g. pickers).
After a bit of research on the web and on Twitter, I solved using Method Swizzling which is a practice that consists in exchanging method implementations.

NOTE: This method might be dangerous if not used carefully! Read this discussion on SO: [Dangers of Method Swizzling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5339276/what-are-the-dangers-of-method-swizzling-in-objective-c)

However, this is what to do:

1. Create a UIFont category, like UIFont+CustomSystemFont.
2. Import `<objc/runtime.h>` in your .m file.
3. Leave .h file unmodified and add this code to the .m:

> ```
> +(UIFont *)regularFontWithSize:(CGFloat)size
> {
>   return [UIFont fontWithName:@"Your Font Name Here" size:size];
> }
>
> +(UIFont *)boldFontWithSize:(CGFloat)size
> {
>   return [UIFont fontWithName:@"Your Bold Font Name Here" size:size];
> }
> ```

// Method Swizzling

```
+(void)load
{
    SEL original = @selector(systemFontOfSize:);
    SEL modified = @selector(regularFontWithSize:);
    SEL originalBold = @selector(boldSystemFontOfSize:);
    SEL modifiedBold = @selector(boldFontWithSize:);

    Method originalMethod = class_getClassMethod(self, original);
    Method modifiedMethod = class_getClassMethod(self, modified);
    method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, modifiedMethod);

    Method originalBoldMethod = class_getClassMethod(self, originalBold);
    Method modifiedBoldMethod = class_getClassMethod(self, modifiedBold);
    method_exchangeImplementations(originalBoldMethod, modifiedBoldMethod);
}
```

Comment: Hey Matteodv!! This is a great work 100+ from my side. You same a lot of work and time for me.....

Comment: Is this within Apple's guidelines? It would definitely help me...

Comment: Yes, it allowed by Apple's guidelines since I updated my application for iOS 7 using this methods and I had no problems!

Comment: It's oddly not working for all of my views: The font used in UITextView placeholders, for instance, is still the original system font. Do you have a solution for that?

Comment: ^ same for me any fix @Redwarp