# how to apply app level NsUrlSession interceptor? iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession

I am developing a framework where i wanna apply interceptor for all network calls,

i have managed to add interceptor at single object level, n figuring out how to add it on app level without adding my guard class each time.

code for adding interceptor at object level

```
func getURLSessionConfiguration() -> URLSessionConfiguration
    {
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
            configuration.protocolClasses?.append(MyURLProtocol.self)
    return configuration
}


let defaultSession = URLSession(configuration: getURLSessionConfiguration())
```

Comment: You can wrap your URLSession you like.

Comment: i wanna apply it to all library that use NSUrlSession in the app

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know of is to swizzle the init method for `NSURLSessionConfiguration` and wrap the method's existing implementation with code that pre-injects your NSURLProtocol into the set of protocols.

If you do swizzle, be sure to do so by writing a C function that calls the original IMP directly, passing it the original selector, not by renaming the method.

For details, see [What are the Dangers of Method Swizzling in Objective C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5339276/what-are-the-dangers-of-method-swizzling-in-objective-c/8636521#8636521).

Comment: does appstore allows this config ?