# Disable text editing when input view is set for text field

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uipickerview, uikeyboard

How to disable editing `textField` manually. I have `UIPickerView` that I want to use as inputView. But seems I still have ability to copy paste in textfield.

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9116969/how-to-disable-uitextfield-editing-but-still-accept-touch) and seems that's what I am looking for, but sources below don't help me

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    questionField.resignFirstResponder();
    // Additional code here
    return false
}
```

Keyboard never gets screen in this case.

Answer (score 0):

[IQDropDownTextField](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQDropDownTextField)

```
textfield.dropDownMode = .datePicker
textfield.delegate = self

//IQDropDownTextFieldDelegate

    func textField(textField: IQDropDownTextField, didSelectDate date: NSDate?){}
```

I have done this way try this.