# Make textfield touch disabled but still accept editing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitextfield

My question is the opposite of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9116969/how-to-disable-uitextfield-editing-but-still-accept-touch).

I have multiple text fields and am setting one text field to be the first responder by default but I don't want them clicking on different text views and going to them manually. I still want the text fields to be editable. Is there a way to disable the user from touching a text field to edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `UITextField` subclass and override `hitTest point` method and return `nil`

```
class CustomTextField: UITextField {
    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Use the custom class in the view controllers. In `viewDidAppear` use `becomeFirstResponder` in the first textfield, in `textFieldShouldReturn` method move to next textfield. Make sure to set delegate to all textfields.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    let textField1 = CustomTextField()
    let textField2 = CustomTextField()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .white

        textField1.delegate = self
        textField1.returnKeyType = .next
        view.addSubview(textField1)

        textField2.delegate = self
        textField2.returnKeyType = .send
        view.addSubview(textField2)

        //add constraints or set frame
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        textField1.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if textField == textField1 {
            textField2.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is an option..... try this...

```
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool
    {
        // Try to find next responder
        if let nextField = textField.superview?.viewWithTag(textField.tag + 1) as? UITextField {
            textField.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            nextField.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            nextField.becomeFirstResponder()
        } else {
            // Not found, so remove keyboard.
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
        }
        // Do not add a line break
        return false
    }
```

Its up to you if you want to disable or leave it enable the current textfield.

I forgot to mention that you must set to disable the User interaction property first, and add tags to each textfield too